# Having trouble showing errors generated by express validator on html page with node express and ejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs, express-validator

I am using nodejs, ejs, express, & express-validator. I am trying to use express validator on my registration page (signup,ejs). Express-validator generates the errors in an array of objects. When I console.log the results (in var errors) I get:

```html
      formatter: [Function: formatter],
      errors:
       [ { value: 'kl',
           msg: 'Username must be between 4 and 15 characters.',
           param: 'username',
           location: 'body' },
         { value: 'kl',
           msg: 'Password must be between 8 and 100 characters.',
           param: 'password',
           location: 'body' },
         { value: 'klsdflksdf',
           msg: 'Passwords must match.',
           param: 'confirmPassword',
           location: 'body' } ] }
```

When I try to iterate the array on my view page (signup.ejs) using For Of I get the error that err is not iterable. When I use For In (shown below), the result is two items showing on my view page. the first is Fromatoer and the second is errors. How do I get the msg: valuse showing? replacing  with <% errors.msg %> produces nothing on the views page.

Here is my views page:

```html
    <%- include('includes/navigation.ejs') %>
    <% if (typeof errors !== "undefined") { %>
        <p>there are errors on page</p>
    <% for(const error in errors) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <li>  <%= error %>  </li>
    </div>
    <% } %>
    <% } %>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="signup-form" action="/signup" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword"
                    placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here is my Controller:

```html
exports.postSignup = [
    check('username', 'Username field must not be empty.').not().isEmpty(),
    check('username', 'Username must be between 4 and 15 characters.').isLength(4, 15),
    check('password', 'Password must be between 8 and 100 characters.').isLength(8, 100),
    check('confirmPassword', 'Passwords must match.').equals('password'),
    (req, res, next) => {

        const username = req.body.username;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;

        const errors = validationResult(req);


        if (errors) {
            console.log(errors);

            res.render('signup', {
                pageTitle: 'Registration Error',
                errors: errors
            });
        } else {
            User.create({
                username: req.body.username,
                password: req.body.password
            })
                .then(result => {
                    res.render('login', { pageTitle: "Signup Successfull" });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        };
    }
];
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. `for in` is meant to be used for iteration over object properties and not best for use with Arrays. For that `Array.forEach` or `for of` is better.

Answer (score 0):

The way you check if any validation error exist should be different. After this line of code you do not get the iterable array.

```
const errors = validationResult(req);
```

You need to use `isEmpty()` method to check if any error exist; and `array()` method to convert `errors` to iterable array.
Typically error handlers look like:

```
const errorHandler = (req, res, next) => {
    let errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        errors = errors.array();
        // some other stuff
    } else next();
};
```

Source: [express-validator docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)